# Problem with Bash script: 'declare: not found'

Tags: bash, scripts

I had a script which was running fine but when I ran it today, it says `declare: not found`. I am using bash shell and path at the starting of the script is correct.

Two flagged lines in my script are as follows:

```
declare -a RESPONSE
RESPONSE=($RESULT)
```

It also says `(` is unexpected but I guess that is coming up because of the first error.
Worth mentioning point is when I type in declare directly works fine.

`declare | grep USER` shows

```
USER=ashfame
USERNAME=ashfame
           values="$SVN_BASH_USERNAME";
```

So, whats wrong here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Are you using `sh` instead of `bash`? `sh` (linked to `dash`) does not support `declare` keyword, nor the syntax

```
VAR=(list)
```

for initializing arrays.

Comment: My shebang line is `#!/bin/bash` only. Did you mean how I execute it? I just tried executing it as `./script.sh` and it worked. But it doesn't work as `script.sh` or `sh script.sh` and I am pretty much sure I used to use only the latter two methods while I created it a week ago. What could explain that?

Comment: @Ashfame: maybe a week ago it missed the features specific to bash you have now, so it worked also with sh script.sh

Comment: No I meant exactly this script used to work a week or two weeks ago. Or you meant some update might have made a change?

Comment: @Ashfame: I don't know, this script, as you show it now, cannot work with sh script.sh.

Answer (score 11):

I suspect that your "shebang" line (the optional first line of the file) is referencing `sh` instead of `bash`.  It should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

for bash scripts.  If the first line of your script is

```
#!/bin/sh
```

then that would indicate that a strictly bourne-compatible shell is to be used; in the case of Ubuntu, `dash` is used.  In many other distributions, this does not cause a problem, because they link `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`; however ubuntu links to `/bin/dash` in order to allow system scripts to run more rapidly.

The `declare` builtin is one of `bash`'s many extensions to the Bourne shell script specification; `dash` just implements that specification without extensions.

Comment: My shebang line is `#!/bin/bash` only

Comment: @Ashfame: how are you running the script?  If you are invoking it by just typing the name of the script, the shebang line will determine what interpreter runs it.  However, if you explicitly invoke it via `sh thescript.sh`, the `sh` shell — i.e. `dash` will interpret it.

Comment: @intuited I was running it through `sh script.sh`. I understand what you said, but I have read somewhere that with this method, `bash` will interpret it. Why would `dash` get it role here? Is it with Ubuntu only? May be what I read was for linux in general.

Comment: @Ashfame with `sh script` you are running the command `sh` with the argument `script`, which makes sh read and execute the commands in that file. The shebang is not read by sh, it starts with a `#`, so it's treated as a comment. If you instead run `./script`, then the kernel will read the shebang, which in your case is `#!/bin/bash`, and so it executes `/bin/bash ./script`

Comment: @geirha yes thats how I know it works but @intuited mention that `dash` will be used, so I need to clarify it

Comment: @Ashfame: `dash` is used because that's what `sh` actually is.  The command `which sh` will tell you what file is being found in the path and executed when you use the `sh` command.  On Ubuntu this is `/bin/sh`.  `ls -l /bin/sh` will further reveal that that file is a symbolic link to `dash` (in that same directory).  To be really thorough you can do `ls -l /bin/dash` to verify that the dash file is not itself a symbolic link to yet another file.

Comment: @Ashfame: Also: the advice about `bash` being run to handle `sh` commands is true on some distributions, just not on Ubuntu. Some other distributions symlink `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`, so on those distros, running `sh somebashscript.sh` will work more or less* the same as `bash somebashscript.sh`. —————— *: There are some differences, because `bash` will behave differently when the given command was actually `sh`. There are gory details about this in bash's voluminous manpage, but you likely don't need to read them. Just be aware that in order to run a bash script on Ubuntu, you type `bash`.

Comment: @Ashfame:  . . . or you can just invoke the script itself, after having made it executable.  E.G. `chmod u+x thescript.sh; ./thescript.sh arg1 arg2`.  The shebang line is only used when the script itself is invoked in this way.

Answer (score 3):

### How to reproduce the above error:

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.  Put this code in a file:

```
#!/bin/sh 
declare -i FOOBAR=12; 
echo $FOOBAR;
```

Run it like this:

```
el@apollo:~$ ./06.sh 
./test.sh: 2: ./test.sh: declare: not found
```

To fix it, do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i FOOBAR=12;
echo $FOOBAR;
```

Prints:

```
el@apollo:~$ ./06.sh 
12
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and then I remembered that you need to assign the right permissions to execute the shell script.

Change permission of the script, for example:

```
chmod 755 script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running your script using `/bin/bash` in command line instead if `sh` (:

Instead of :

```
    sh script.sh
```

Try :

```
    /bin/bash script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, you may have a script which is executing other scripts within it, which I have run into.

```
some_dir/  
        | main.sh  
        | shhh.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "file? $0"
# file? ./main.sh

echo "shell? $SHELL" 
# shell? /bin/bash

# sh shhh.sh
# file? shhh.sh
# shell? /bin/bash
# shhh.sh: 5: shhh.sh: declare: not found

$SHELL shhh.sh
# file? shhh.sh
# shell? /bin/bash
# foo? bar
```

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "file? $0"
# shhh.sh

echo "shell? $SHELL"
# shell? /bin/bash

declare foo="bar"

echo "foo? $foo"
```

Changing all `sh some_script.sh` to `$SHELL some_script.sh` fixed it.