# Detect cancelling zenity when script is run as sudo

Tags: bash, zenity

I use `Ubuntu 14.04` and have a simple script:

```
OUTPUT=$(zenity --forms\
 --title="new"\
 --text="Add new"\
 --separator="," \
    --add-entry="path"\
 )
accepted=$?
if ((accepted != 0)); then
    echo "process is cancelled!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "$OUTPUT"
```

When I run it normally and press cancel button, there is no problem. But when I run that as sudo I get this error:

```
/path/to/test.sh: 8: /path/to/test.sh: accepted: not found
```

Although I could solve problem like this:

```
if ! OUTPUT=$(zenity --forms\
 --title="new"\
 --text="Add new"\
 --separator="," \
    --add-entry="path"\
 ); then
echo "Cancelled"
fi

echo "$OUTPUT"
```

But I want to know what does cause that problem?

Comment: Are you trying to write this in `sh` format or `bash` format? [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28311/problem-with-bash-script-declare-not-found) could be helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm going to mark this as a duplicate of that question as it has been solved.